# How to save product image as in PNG extension in prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, save-image

In Prestashop 1.7 all the images save as "***jpg***" format. I want to save all the product image as ***PNG*** format. Am a new to prestashop, Please anybody help me to save the images as ***PNG*** format.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your backoffice go to `Design -> Image Settings` the scroll down until you see the box with this title 'IMAGES GENERATION OPTIONS', then change the `Image format` option, click on:
 `Use PNG only if the base image is in PNG format.`
 or
 `Use PNG for all images.` 
then click save :).

Now the images will saved in PNG format ;)

Comment: Thanks Sarcom, It's working. I Got the image in PNG format But in the image (img/p/....) directory it's saved as .jpg extension. But it's fine.

Thanks again...

Comment: Yes I know, unfortunately it has always been so :)